# How to avoid error Cannot read property of undefined using two LWC Wired properties

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

How to avoid error Cannot read property of undefined using LWC Wired properties but to display two properties?
[image]afterRender threw an error in 'c:tryc' [Cannot read property 'x' of undefined]

HTML file of `tryc.html`

```
<template>
    x.data {x.data}<br/>
    y.data {y.data}<br/>
    x.data.x {x.data.x}<br/>
    y.data.y {y.data.y}<br/>
</template>
```

Listing of `Tryc.js`

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getX from '@salesforce/apex/TryCont.getX'; 
import getY from '@salesforce/apex/TryCont.getY'; 

export default class Tryc extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getX)
    x
    @wire(getY)
    y
}
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class TryCont {

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, Object> getX() {
        return new Map<String, Object>{'x'=>'y'};
    }
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, Object> getY() {
        return new Map<String, Object>{'y'=>'x'};
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid this problems, it is needed to surround the code with `<template if:true` tag, usually it is clear and obvious when we rely on load of one parameter. However, when the code depends on two parameters, it is needed to add
additional property which would track if both properties has been loaded

```
@api
get loaded() {
    return !!this.x.data && !!this.y.data;
}
```

Modified template

```
<template>

    <template if:true={loaded}>
        loaded!<br/>
        x.data {x.data}<br/>
        y.data {y.data}<br/>
        x.data.x {x.data.x}<br/>
        y.data.y {y.data.y}<br/>
    </template>

</template>
```

And final version of Lightning Javascript Web Module

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getX from '@salesforce/apex/TryCont.getX'; 
import getY from '@salesforce/apex/TryCont.getY'; 

export default class Tryc extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getX)
    x
    @wire(getY)
    y
    @api
    get loaded() {
        return !!this.x.data && !!this.y.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Great answer. You shouldn't need the `@api` on the `loaded` getter though since that will only be called from the same components template file.

Comment: I can't make it @ track to rerender the component once value of loaded is changed so I must use @ api

Comment: @TrevorBliss so I am afraid that if I remove api decorator, lightning web component will not be rerendered once the value of loaded is changed, so it will hang in the unloaded state or will load immediately if user is lucky

Comment: You don’t need `@api` or `@track` on getters referenced from the template. Your getter relies on reactive `@wire` properties. The system understand transitive dependencies.